# Fork Join mechanism in Java 7

Tags: concurrency, java-7, fork-join

Does the scheduling mechanism implemented in Fork Join necessarily entail that if at any point of time there are free cores available, threads will definitely be scheduled on those free cores?

Comment: I don't know specifically about fork/join on Java 7, but concurrency libaries *tend* not to give that specific guarantees. Why are you interested in that?

Comment: Hi Joachim, The difference between Executor and fork join in working is work stealing and in concept is divide and conquer. But what about scheduling and hence my question.